# Build a modulated square wave

Tags: c++, frequency, trigonometry

I need to construct a modulated square wave from several known carrier frequencies and I don't know what I'm doing. I need this to test demodulation code I will be using once my hardware is ready to go.

I have a simulator class who's overloaded method returns a sample of data:

I have a var x that is incremented by one for every sample.
Sample rate = 31680. Carrier frequencies start at 7800 and step 120. For the purposes of this method lets just do the first 6.

1hz and amplitude of 1

```
float getSample(){


   _x++;
}
```

I have seen examples as simple as fluctuating from a +- constant for a given number of samples to more comprehensive methods such as summing sine waves ([Like Here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-7/square-wave-signals/)) but none seem to be working with modulated carrier frequencies.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: its not clear, what is your question. Seems like it is about signal processing rather than coding

Comment: Sounds like your first step is to create a function which synthesises a simple sin wave 7.8KHz with a sample rate of 31680 Hz.

Comment: I had a misunderstanding in what the modulation of n square waves at different frequencies would look like. Different frequencies cause different wavelengths, which causes the +- component of the amplitude to be different for each wave at a given time point. Now I can code it.